# Foxpro get logical value from combobox?

Tags: combobox, visual-foxpro

I have gender comboxbox with column 1 is gender name (male/female) and column 2 is value (1/0).
In the database, the gender field is logical. How can I get the logical value from the combobox to insert to db?

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor or table should have the first column be the display column and the second column should be the ID column.

Then in the combo control, the rowsourcetype should be = 2, the rowsource should be the name of your cursor or table and the boundcolumn should be 2 and the controlsource should be set to the table.column name that will store the selected gender.

Answer (score 0):

On your form, right-click on the combobox and click builder.  On the first tab set the combobox to "Data entered by hand", then set the column count to 2.  For the data entry, put in row 1 your value for Male in the first column and 1 in the second column (assuming 1 = Male).  On the second row, put in the value for Female and 0 in the second column.

On the second tab for Style, change the combo to "Drop-down List"

On the third  tab, change the column widths in case you want to hide the actual second column of 0/1 so the user doesn't see it, just shrink the second column to no width.

On the fourth tab, set the combobox to column2 as that is your 1/0 representation of male/female.

But your actual question listed 0/1 vs logical in VFP of .T. and .F.

So, if you did intend to do logical, just change the 0/1 references to .f. / .t. respectively.